# Simple server built on top of Raspbian refuses connections- fix?

Tags: ruby, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Recently I have gotten a Raspberry Pi, and my first project I decided to build was a simple server that returns 'Hello World' to any and all clients. This is the code:

```
require 'socket' # Provides TCPServer and TCPSocket classes
puts 'initializing, standby'
server = TCPServer.new('localhost', 2345)
loop do

socket = server.accept
puts 'hello, this is alien'
request = socket.gets
STDERR.puts request
response = "Hello World!\n"
socket.print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
           "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" +
           "Content-Length: #{response.bytesize}\r\n" +
           "Connection: close\r\n"
socket.print "\r\n"
socket.print response
socket.close

end
```

When I run that, the command line outputs `initializing, standby`. But then when I go to a browser and put in `http://localhost:2345/anything`, it returns connection refused. Changing `localhost` to its IP address or hostname does not work either. I *have* successfully SSHed to the raspberry pi. What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: you should use the ip address of the Raspberry pi, also you want to confirm you don't have firewalls turned on, either on your router or on the raspberry pi, on the raspberry pi you can run `sudo iptables -Lvn` to check if you have firewall on the raspberry pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
server = TCPServer.new('localhost', 2345)
```

means  the server only listens connections from localhost. You can access it from the pi that is:

```
curl localhost:2345
```

But if you want to access the server from outside the pi, the server has to listen connections from anywhere like the following:

```
server = TCPServer.new('0.0.0.0', 2345)
```

Comment: Why '0.0.0.0' versus any other IP address?

Comment: This might be useful: http://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1